# RecyclerView Becomes Focused when DrawerLayout is Closed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout

This is sort of a strange bug I discovered.

But if I have a RecyclerView in a fragment and I open then close my DrawerLayout, my RecyclerView comes in focus. That means closing my DrawerLayout will cause the ScrollView to jump to my RecyclerView. Obviously, I would like the ScrollView's position to not move when the DrawerLayout is closed, and definitely not settle on my RecyclerView.

---

**CODE**

Throughout my application, I have RecyclerViews contained within ScrollViews, similar to this setup:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:tint="#80000000"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/header_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_SecondaryColor"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/header_xxlarge"/>

                <View android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/hr_thick"
                    android:background="@color/accent_PrimaryColor"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/button_more"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_width="400px"
                android:layout_height="100px"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_dark"
                android:textColor="@drawable/button_dark_textcolor"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And my DrawerLayout's XML design is arranged like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentframe"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/background_Secondary">

        <!-- Relative Layout : Back Button -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_backcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/angle"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- List View : Menu Drawer Content -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_below="@id/menu_backcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:background="@color/background_PrimaryDarkColor">
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am not sure what other Java Code I need to include here but this is how I instantiate my RecyclerView:

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

And For My DrawerLayout:

```
drawerlayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
menu = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu);
MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.listview_menuitem,
        menuItemArray);
menu.setAdapter(adapter);
menu.setOnItemClickListener(new menuItemClickListener());

menuToggle =  new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawerlayout,
        toolbar,
        R.string.app_name,
        R.string.app_name);
   drawerlayout.setDrawerListener(menuToggle);
   menuToggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gee, it is amazing what a moment away from the computer and a cup of coffee will do.

I simply set the `focusableInTouchMode` attribute of my FrameLayout to `true`.

I guess this nullifies the RecyclerViews desire to be the focused element in the ScrollView when I touch anywhere on the screen after the DrawerLayout is opened. Perhaps there is a better, more thorough explanation. But I hope this helps anyone else who may experience this problem.